# What are the allowed characters in a css property and a css value

Tags: css, properties, html-agility-pack

I am writing a C# forms application where a user can create some css rules. Each css rule object is comprised of a property and a value.

My question is this: What are the validation rules for both properties and values? What are the allowed characters and the characters that are not allowed. The user enters these values into a textbox, and as such, the data type I am dealing with is a string for both the property and the value.

I am currently using Html Agility Pack to create html nodes, and to validate these, I create an html node, with a try catch block to see if the values are valid. Can a similar concept be used for css rules?

**EDIT**

I am not wanting to validate a css style sheet. All that I am needing to do is to ensure that a name/value pair is valid.

Is there some official documentation of the allowed and disallowed values? Are the values just html attribute name value pairs? Can this be done with regular expressions, and if so, where can I find the correct regex statement?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by longtext?

Comment: WRT your edit: of course there is documentation about what is valid. But different properties have different valid values! There is no single rule for "any valid CS value".

Comment: For instance, there are textual values that can be anything, as long as it's in quotes. `content` for instance. No restrictions whatsoever for what's between the quotation marks. Other properties are much more restricted; `width` for instance can only take values from the character set `%*()-+/0123456789acehilmnprtvwx` (and then not even in any order). `z-index` only takes a number.