# where is CSS meta structure defined; what makes a CSS "well formed"

Tags: css, parsing

pre: this is not a CSS tips or tricks question.

The question is *what is syntactically allowed* not *what is semantically correct*

This is probably a dup of [What are the allowed characters in a css property and a css value [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31404102/what-are-the-allowed-characters-in-a-css-property-and-a-css-value), but the "duplicate" answer there is IMHO not the answer to the question

I want to use "user defined properties" and parse CSS server side.

The scenario: my customer is able to style his reports using a CSS file. There are charts in this report and I want to let style them via a rule - like this:

```
div.sell-types {
    width:60mm;
    height:60mm;
    float:left;
    -user-chart: pie green red blue 10%; // pie chart, colors to use, put values <10% into one
    -user-number-format: 2 ",."  // ie. 10,000.00 works, but ok?
    }
```

I parse this CSS server side and can now render the chart as desired.

The browser just ignores this -user-xxx per definition.

All this is up and running, but the *CSS parsing process is still based on trial and error*.

So I am *not* interested in allowed property/value combinations, so when parsing my only interest is the -user-xxx property.

To make an example:

```
div { 
    height: blue; /* wrong :-) */
    }
```

is wrong, but if the customer wants a blue height, he gets it, the syntax is OK. while

```
div { 
    height: b l u e; /* wrong, but syntax ok - I would think */
    width: gr:een;  /* very bad - I think */  
    back ground: blue; /* very bad - I think */
    reminder: 'mothers day' /* syntax ok - I would think */
    }
```

are partially syntactically wrong.

But where is this defined? I would like to remove the "I would think" above.

EDIT: Since the customers delivers a SCSS and I parse the compiler output, I expect a syntactically correct CSS

Comment: User defined properties are prefixed with a double dash, like `--user-chart` for example. See [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_variables).

Comment: It's pretty much a case of "split on `;` and check each piece independently", so if one property-value pair is invalid, that item is just ignored. This is different to selectors though, where any of the options separated by `,` being invalid causes the whole selector tofail.

Comment: Expanding on what @NiettheDarkAbsol said, it's up to the browser to determine exactly what "invalid syntax" fails and what is let through. You should not rely on browsers to parse semantically invalid CSS and leave valid rules in the same selector unaffected, this will cause inconsistent behavior.

Answer (score 0):

1. The correct answer

here: [CSS Syntax Module Level 3 - W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/)

Have fun with chapters **4 Tokenization** and **5 Parsing**!

2. The wrong answer

"split on ';' and then on ':'", because both can't (and will sooner or later) be part of eg.

```
`background-image: url(...);`
```

3. The moderate - pragmatic answer:

If you don't expect somebody to play games with you, so if you have control over the CSS input somehow, you will be on a save side, if you take care of ';:' within paranthesis (all kinds) and quotes ("" and ''), so the usual suspects